# Neumann boundary conditions diffusion equations methods of lines

Tags: boundary-conditions, diffusion, method-of-lines

I want to solve the diffusion equation using the method of lines with Neumann boundary conditions
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial x^2}\\
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x=0)=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x=1)=0\\
p(x,0)=\begin{cases}
       1/dx \quad x=0.5,\\
        0 \quad  elsewhere
\end{cases}
$$
For sake of simplicity I use the forward Euler so I choose $dx=0.1, \; dt=0.001$ to ensure the stability.
Using a second order scheme I solve the boundary conditions imposing
$$
\frac{p_1-p_{-1}}{2 dx}=0,\\
\frac{p_{N+1}-p_{N-1}}{2 dx}=0.\\
$$
So the tridiagonal matrix looks like 
$$
\frac{1}{dx^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2&2&0&0\\
1&-2&1&0\\
0&1&-2&1\\
0&0&2&-2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
At this point the solution of my equation is given by
$$
\vec{p}^{k+1}=dt(T\vec{p}^k)+\vec{p}^k.
$$
This boundary conditions impose the conservation of probability but it seems that is not the case since for different $N$ (number of grid points on the $x$ axis) I obtain different probabilities. For example, for $N=10,20,100,1000$ I obtained that the total probability is $1.11111,1.05263,1.00012,1.0000$.
It seems that I need a really fine grid to obtain the correct physical result.

Did I make a conceptual mistake or I just made an error in my code?
Thank for the answers

Comment: Your discretised system is an approximation and the finite difference method is not exactly conservative. If use used finite volume method, which is conservative discretisation it would improve. I think 1000 points is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that the function
\begin{equation}
P(t) := \int \limits_0^1 p(x,t) \, \mathrm{d}x, \quad t \geq 0,
\end{equation}
is constant over time (i. e. $P(t) = P(0)$, $\forall \, t \geq 0$), if $p$ is a solution of your initial-boundary-value problem.

If you discretize the problem in space as you described, then you obtain a system of linear ordinary differential equations in time of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt} = \boldsymbol{\underline{T}} \boldsymbol{p}
\end{equation}
for the vector-valued function $\boldsymbol{p}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, with the tridiagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\underline{T}} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N+1) \times (N+1)}$ that you have specified.

Now if you define some function $\tilde{P}(t) := \boldsymbol{c}^{\top} \boldsymbol{p}(t)$, $t \geq 0$, with a vector $\boldsymbol{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, then this function will be constant over time (i. e. $\tilde{P}(t) = \tilde{P}(0)$, $\forall \, t \geq 0$) if and only if $\frac{d\tilde{P}}{dt} = 0$. The time derivative of $\tilde{P}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\tilde{P}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(\boldsymbol{c}^{\top}\boldsymbol{p}) = \boldsymbol{c}^{\top} \frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt} = \boldsymbol{c}^{\top} \boldsymbol{\underline{T}} \boldsymbol{p},
\end{equation}
and the right-hand side is zero for any $\boldsymbol{p}$ if and only if $\boldsymbol{c}^{\top} \boldsymbol{\underline{T}} = \boldsymbol{0}_{\mathbb{R}^{N+1}}^{\top}$. For your tridiagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\underline{T}}$ this is satisfied if and only if
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{c}^{\top} = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \cdots & 1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \tilde{P} = \boldsymbol{c}^{\top} \boldsymbol{p} = \frac{1}{2} p_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} p_i + \frac{1}{2} p_N.
\end{equation}
This corresponds to using the trapezoidal rule for the approximation of the integral in $P$. If you calculate your $\tilde{P}$ in any other way then its value will not be constant over time for this discretization.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a uniform grid
$$
x_i = ih, \quad i=0,1,\ldots,N
$$
Your equations are
$$
dp_0/dt = 2(p_1 - p_0)/h^2
$$
$$
dp_i/dt = (p_{i-1} - 2 p_i + p_{i+1})/h^2, \quad 1 \le i \le N-1
$$
$$
dp_N/dt = 2(p_{N-1} - p_N)/h^2
$$
This can also be written as
$$
dp/dt = Tp, \qquad p = [p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_N]^\top
$$
where $T$ is tridiagonal matrix. Compute integral of $p$ by Trapezoidal rule
$$
I(t) = \left(p_0/2 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} p_i + p_N/2\right) h
$$
Using the scheme
$$
dI/dt = \frac{1}{h} \left(p_1 - p_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} (p_{i-1} - 2 p_i + p_{i+1}) + p_{N-1} - p_N \right)
$$
Rearrange the sum to show that
$$
dI/dt = 0
$$

It is not clear from the question how the total probability was calculated. As shown above, using Trapezoidal rule, the numerical scheme will conserve the total probability.

Comment: Trapezoidal rule isn't required for this to work.

Comment: To calculate the the probability I just summed the entries of the vector p after a fixed time of time steps and then I multiplied by dx to take in account the normalization. I totally do not understand what you integrate; I do not understand how you find the solution of the PDE

Comment: I have written each equation from your matrix form. You are calculating total probability wrongly. Do it with Trapezoidal rule and your scheme will conserve total probability.